# Interoperability: Fortran to C++

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I would like to develop a **Fortran Static Library** that include a custom subroutine that takes **a long time to complete.**
This static library will be linked in my C++ application statically too.

My goal is **monitoring** the current status of this subroutine in my C++ application **in real-time.**

So, **for each step** of a "fortran loop", I would like to **send the loop index** to my C++ application.

**I'm new in Fortran world**, so I was thinking that this task could be something like this:

**My C++ header:**

`extern "C" void fortran_status(int* value);`

**My Fortran-90 file:**

```
module my_interfaces
    use iso_c_binding
        interface
            subroutine fortran_status(progress_value) bind(C, name = 'fortran_status')
                use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
                integer(c_int), intent(out) :: progress_value
            end subroutine fortran_status
        end interface
end module my_interfaces


! My long calc subroutine
subroutine my_long_calc(progress_value) BIND(C, name = 'my_long_calc')
    use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
    use my_interfaces
    implicit none

    EXTERNAL fortran_status

    integer (C_INT), INTENT(INOUT) :: progress_value
    integer (C_INT) :: count


    do count = 0, 5    
        progress_value = progress_value + 1

        ! Send 'progress_value' to a C++ function:
        call fortran_status(progress_value)

        ! Wait 1 second:
        call sleep(1)
    end do

end subroutine my_long_calc
```

This Fortran code gives me a **compile-time error:**

```
error #6406: Conflicting attributes or multiple declaration of name.   [FORTRAN_STATUS]       C:\Users\lamar\Desktop\Lib1_interface\Lib1.f90    18
```

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 with Intel Visual Fortran (Windows 10 x64).

How could I **monitoring that subroutine status? Or get the fortran loop index in my C++ application?**

### UPDATE 1:

I removed the `EXTERNAL fortran_status` and now I got no errors in compile-time of my Fortran code.

Now, I would like to link this static Lib (x86) with my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  void my_long_calc(void);
  void fortran_status(int* value);
}

void fortran_status(int* value)
{
  std::cout << "Fortran current status = " << *value << std::endl;
}

int main (void)
{
  std::cout << "Monitoring Fortran subroutine..." << std::endl;

  my_long_calc();

  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to compile and link it using MingW:

`g++ -Wall -L. .\Lib2.lib -lgfortran .\main.cpp -o app.exe`

And I got this linker error:
`undefined reference to my_long_calc`

**How can I link it?**

I would like to see in my terminal output:

```
Monitoring Fortran subroutine...

Fortran current status = 0
Fortran current status = 1
Fortran current status = 2
​​​​​​​Fortran current status = 3
​​​​​​​Fortran current status = 4
​​​​​​​Fortran current status = 5
```

### UPDATE 2

Now this changed Fortran code compiles and it work well **ONLY if I'm using MingW g++ (x86).**

**Fortran code:**

```
module my_interfaces
  use iso_c_binding
  interface
    subroutine fortran_status(progress_value) bind(C, name = 'fortran_status')
      use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
      integer(c_int), intent(out) :: progress_value
    end subroutine fortran_status
  end interface
end module my_interfaces


! My long calc subroutine
subroutine my_long_calc() BIND(C, name = 'my_long_calc')
  use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
  use my_interfaces
  implicit none

  integer (C_INT) :: progress_value
  integer (C_INT) :: count

  progress_value = 0

  do count = 0, 5
    progress_value = count

    ! Send 'progress_value' to a C++ function:
    call fortran_status(progress_value)

    ! Wait 1 second:
    call sleep(1)
  end do
end subroutine my_long_calc
```

**C++ Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    void my_long_calc(void);
    void fortran_status(int* value);
}

void fortran_status(int* value)
{
    std::cout << "Fortran current status = " << *value << std::endl;
}

int main (void)
{
    std::cout << "Monitoring Fortran subroutine..." << std::endl;

    my_long_calc();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile c++: `g++ -Wall -c .\main.cpp`

Compile fortran: `gfortran -c .\gfortran.f90`

Link all together: `g++ .\main.o .\gfortran.o -o app.exe -lgfortran`

The problem now is that **I need to use Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Fortran to develop my Fortran Code.**
And I would like to compile all Fortran code to a **single static library (*.lib) file** using Visual Studio.

**What I need to change** to get to link the *.lib file (from Visual Fortran) using the MingW g++ command?

I was thinking to use something like this:
`g++ main.cpp my_lib.lib -o app.exe`

**But I got this linker error:**
`undefined reference to my_long_calc`

What I need to do?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `external fortran_status` because you've already given a definition on that interface in the module.  So we can explain further, why do you think that `external` statement is necessary?

Comment: Thank you @francescalus! You are right! Now I got no erros at compile-time in my fortran code. Thanks!

Comment: The complete answer and some details are here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/815889#comment-1943689

Answer (score 3):

The code in your "Update 2" is perfectly fine and works with Intel Visual Fortran and Microsoft Visual C++. See also the discussion you started in https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Interoperability-Fortran-to-C/m-p/1144147

I do not recommend mixing Intel Visual Fortran compiled objects/libraries with g++ on Windows. You can get Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition free if you meet the rather liberal license terms. If you insist on using g++, mix it with gfortran.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead. There is also link here https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/New-Interoperability-Fortran-to-C-String-case/m-p/1144668 but it also leads nowhere.

Comment: @VladimirF Which link are you looking for?

Comment: To the discussion post linked in the answer. It does bot lead anywhere now.

Comment: I found the new link and updated my post above.