# how can I use fastjet with madgraph at fixed order?

Tags: c++, fortran, physics

I'm trying to apply clustering jet techniques from fastjet with madgraph at fixed order. The code or the histogram with uncertainties is written in fortran and the classes in fastjet are in c++. so my question is how can I link the code written in fortran with the classes written in c++ i.e. fastjet with madgraph ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interoperability: Fortran to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481192/interoperability-fortran-to-c)